# wpf documentviewer and simple text

Tags: c#, wpf, text, documentviewer

I need to dispay text for user before printing and allow to print it.
I try to use DocumentViewer, but can't find example to display simple Text. Only Word or XPS, but it's overgear solutions.

Is there any way to print simple multiline text throw DocumentViewer

```
var printText = @"Multiline text to view and print
Line1 Content
Line2 Content
";
```

and View

```
<DocumentViewer>
    <FixedDocument></FixedDocument>
</DocumentViewer>
```

How to make this work ?

Comment: This should start you on the right path http://stackoverflow.com/a/10258079/3225

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [FlowDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument(v=vs.110).aspx)?

```
<FlowDocumentReader xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <FlowDocument>
    <Paragraph>
      <Bold>Some bold text in the paragraph.</Bold>
      Some text that is not bold.
    </Paragraph>
    <List>
      <ListItem>
        <Paragraph>ListItem 1</Paragraph>
      </ListItem>
      <ListItem>
        <Paragraph>ListItem 2</Paragraph>
      </ListItem>
      <ListItem>
        <Paragraph>ListItem 3</Paragraph>
      </ListItem>
    </List>
  </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentReader>
```

Comment: @Json76 Then you can give is a check mark indicate it is an answer

Comment: One issue - it's not showing Print button in reader toolbar ( where zoom buttons and other ) as DocumentViewer. Trying set IsPrintEnabled = true not helped.  It's not big problem, but in layout i need reserve place for custom button